# Подгрузка скриптов и стилей к серверу Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-сервер

У меня есть сервер на `Node.js`*(самый простой, без наворотов)*. Помимо файла со страницей, он имеет в виде файла стили(*`style.css`*) и скрипты(*`script.js`*). Они подключены к странице, которую получает пользователь, стандартным путём. Как я понял, пользователь получается только файл страницы, в следствии чего скрипты и стили не работают. Что делать?

Comment: Написать app.get() для стилей и js. А если бы вы ваш код показали, то возможно другое решение нашлось бы

Comment: Пишу с другого аккаунта. Вот код

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

let server = http.createServer((req,res)) => {
    res.writeHead(200, 'Content-Type': 'text/html; encoding=utf-8');
    const stream = fs.createReadStream('./index.html');
    stream.pipe(res);
}).listen(PORT, HOST);
```